# While loop without Condition

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements

Following is the program I encountered

```
#include <stdio.h>       

void sp_to_dash(const char *str);
int main(void)
{
    sp_to_dash("this is a test");
    return 0;
}
void sp_to_dash(const char *str)
{
    while(*str) //beginning of while loop
    {               
        if(*str== ' ')printf("%c", '-');
        else printf("%c", *str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

At the beginning of `while` loop we can see that `while(*str)` is initiated without any condition, which means it is not mentioned that when the `*str` should stop on `null` or `'\0'`. The code is working fine, however according to me it should be like this `while(*str != null)` or `while(*str != '\0')`. Please explain this one to me.

Comment: Saying that the code should be `while(*str != null){...}` clearly indicates that don't have clear the difference between empty strings, null pointers and the `NUL` ASCII character `'\0'` (and BTW the null pointer is `NULL`, not `null`). It's a disease somewhat common among C newbies, but you should fix that as soon as possible.

Comment: i for one am glad you posted this because the below answer helped me too. most c++ tutorials only show examples of explicit test statements and i was encountering while (variable) {} syntaxes and wondering how that works.

Answer (score 2):

It is same as writing this -

```
while (*str != '\0')
```

`'\0'` is of type int and is equivalent to `0` and will not effect execution of loop.

**Note**- Don't compare string with `==` and there is no operator `!==`.

This will cause error if you use this (comparing `char` with string literal) -

```
while (*str != "\0")
```

Comment: Ther is no string in the code that is being compared with == operator

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz OP modified his code , this is result of that . Now he has removed `!==` too .

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz No need to apologise, it is OP's mistake  :)

Answer (score 2):

The while loop needs a value as a condition in order to work. When you insert a condition like `while (*str == '3')`, your condition checks if `*str` actually is `'3'` and if so it is interpreted as `1` (you can think of this as True if you like) and if not, it interprets it as `0` (or False).

This is why you can write `while (0)` or `while (1)`.

Now, your condition is the value of `*str` so, during the condition check, you will check the value of `*str` to see if it is `0` or not *(every other value (-1, 7, 32333.34 ...) considered as True)*  `str` is a `const char *` so we need to translate char value into int values (using ASCII). The `char` that has the value 0 is `'\0'`.

Comment: thank you for explaining the possibilities of the condition check, very helpful to my noob self

Answer (score 0):

It is exectly the same condition as (*str!='\0') because the ascii value of \0 is 0 so the loop will stop when *str will be \0, means  at the end of the string,

*any other value except 0 is a true condition for itself (like *str) and will cause the while loop to continue e,g: while(5){} will be an endless loop.